# AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'checked'

Tags: python, android, selenium, selenium-webdriver, attributes

Got the: `AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'checked'` error for the following block:

```
    wait = WebDriverWait (driver, 15)
    element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"XYZ")))
    for i in element:
        if 'true' == i.checked:
            print('Step 33. Auto update button is ON - PASS')
        else:
            print('Step 33. Auto update button failed to switch - PASS')
    pass
```

As you can see I have a table here with the attributes... but is not recognized.

[Attributes can be seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JqRo.png)

Can anyone help me with that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a web element attribute you should use `.get_attribute()` method.
Try this:

```py
wait = WebDriverWait (driver, 15)
    element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"XYZ")))
    for i in element:
        if 'true' == i.get_attribute("checked"):
            print('Step 33. Auto update button is ON - PASS')
        else:
            print('Step 33. Auto update button failed to switch - PASS')
```